# Need help in creating a function in R to calculate correlations for multiple dataframes

Tags: r, function

I am new to R, and I might be over complicating the code. I am trying to calculate correlations for multiple dataframes that are created using the split function.

So I create multiple dataframe using the code

```
split(select.other,list(select.other$ERPM_RIC_DTL_NM,select.other$SERIES_NM),drop=TRUE)
```

I plan to create a function that would do the following steps

```
t1<-df[c("PD","SERIES_VAL")]
t1$t <- seq.int(nrow(t1))

t2<-t1$t + t1$PD
t3<-t1$t + t1$SERIES_VAL
t<-t1$t

m1 <- lm(t2 ~ t)
m2 <- lm(t3 ~ t)
z1 <- t2 - (m1$coefficients[2]*t1$t) 
z2 <- t3 - (m2$coefficients[2]*t1$t) 
cor(z1,z2)
```

the function would select PD, SERIES_VAL from every dataframe created by the split function and the perform the logic in the code and then output the correlation.

It would be awesome if I can get help in creating a function that would accomplish this. I might be over complicating things for myself and there maybe more easier way. If so, I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance for any help and guidance.

Comment: Hi, it would help if you provided a data sample. You may want to look into `dplyr::group_by` if you are using `split`

Comment: Want to make sure I'm understanding this. Is your question basically 'how do I create a function?'